# Using typeof in lambda expressions

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, properties

I have:

```
CustomObjekt temp = myCustomList.Find(x => typeof(x.myTyp) is T)
```

This is syntactically not correct, what would it be correctly ?

Comment: What type is `x.myTyp` ? Do you need to support inheritance? (ie. `x.myTyp` can either be `T` or **inherit from** `T`?

Comment: hi, `x.myTyp` is declared with `dynamic` , and normally `x.myTyp` contains the value `typeof(AnyObject)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`FirstOrdefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
CustomObjekt temp = myCustomList.OfType<CustomObjekt>().FirstOrDefault();
```

If the object itself is not of that type but you have to check the type of a property, use `Where`:

```
CustomObjekt temp = myCustomList.Where(x => x.myTyp.GetType() == typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault();
```

If it's a `List<T>` you could also replace `Where...FirstOrdefault()` with [`myCustomList.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
CustomObjekt temp = myCustomList.Find(x => x.myTyp.GetType() == typeof(T));
```

Comment: But `typeof(x.myTyp)` won't compile O_o

Comment: And something like `typeof("")` won't compile too... `typeof(x.myTyp)` is absolutely incorrect, isn't it?

Comment: Should and will :D

Comment: Thank you how to adjust  `CustomObjekt temp = myCustomList.Where(x => x.myTyp.GetType() == typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault(); `that it will take of `null` values of `x.myTyp` ?

Comment: @kkkk00999: you could simply use `&&`, for example: `Where(x => x.myTyp != null && x.myTyp.GetType() == typeof(T))`. If you want to include the `null` you have to change `!= null` to `== null`.

Comment: Hi thank you for helping, I changed this to an extra topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450219/taking-care-of-null-value-in-lambda-expressions

Answer (score 0):

This is either incorrect in lambdas, delegates or anywhere.

`typeof` operator is to get the `Type` instance from a given type identifier. For example `typeof(string)`.

In your case, you need to use `Type.IsAssignableFrom`:

```
CustomObjekt temp = myCustomList.Find(x => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(x.myTyp));
```

`Type.IsAssignableFrom` has a benefit over `someType == typeof(T)`: it takes inheritance in account. It's the closest solution to the `is` operator, since `is` expression would also give `true` if `B is A` if `B` inherits `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GetType() like this:

```
CustomObjekt temp = myCustomList.Find(x => x.myTyp.GetType() == typeof(T));
```

Comment: Thank you, but `x.myTyp` is dynamic, so I can not use it like you wrote.